# Making Development Better with Static Analysis

Tags: vba, static-analysis

I find, when I'm reviewing VBA code, that most of the bugs are easily classified errors, such as typos, not setting things to `Nothing`, not closing DB connections, etc.

I know that using "Option Explicit" can solve some of these, but I'd rather use something more powerful.

Are there any static analysis tools for VBA?

Answer (score 6):

You can perhaps start by using [MZ-Tools](http://www.mztools.com/v3/mztools3.aspx). While it does not have much in the realm of static analysis features, it is free and does provide some help in managing and editing your code base.

One feature it has that does perform a form of static analysis is:

- [Review Source Code](http://www.mztools.com/v3/onlinehelp/html_review_source_code.htm)- An extremely
  limited version of code analysis. It
  tells you if a variable,
  constant, or procedure is not being
  used. Good to help clean
  up your code and get rid of cruft.

Comment: +1 for MZTools. Very good tool, mandatory for any VBA developer. VBA IDE is terrible, MZTools makes it a little bit worse.

Comment: I think you mean "... a little less worse"

Answer (score 1):

[Project Analyzer: VBA Plug v3](http://www.aivosto.com/project/vba.html)
[MZ Tools](http://www.mztools.com/v3/mztools3.aspx)
[VBA Code Profiler](http://www.bandwood.com/_Store/commerce.cgi?product=VBACP&cart_id=431008.15085) *

- no idea whether this is supported still, or what the quality of the product is like.

Answer (score 1):

A free/open source option which is actively maintained is [Rubberduck](http://rubberduckvba.com/) ([on GitHub](https://github.com/rubberduck-vba/Rubberduck)).  It includes several static analyzers, which it calls "Inspections".  There is a [list of Inspections](http://rubberduckvba.com/Inspections/List) on their website.